# Failed to pull image with policy "": image pull failed: Back-off pulling image "<image_name>"

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, artifactory

I am getting below error

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.0.0 (3b6f852e)
  on gitlab-runner-artefactory-gitlab-runner-68f94fd89-pnd6g DaN3U_2T
Preparing the "kubernetes" executor
00:00
Using Kubernetes namespace: sai
Using Kubernetes executor with image aie-docker-dev-mydockerrepo/python:3.6-strech ...
Using attach strategy to execute scripts...
Preparing environment
00:06
Waiting for pod sai/runner-dan3u2t-project-9879-concurrent-0zdmgf to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod sai/runner-dan3u2t-project-9879-concurrent-0zdmgf to be running, status is Pending
    ContainersNotReady: "containers with unready status: [build helper svc-0]"
    ContainersNotReady: "containers with unready status: [build helper svc-0]"
WARNING: Failed to pull image with policy "": image pull failed: Back-off pulling image "aie-docker-dev-mydockerrepo/python:3.6-strech"
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): prepare environment: waiting for pod running: pulling image "aie-docker-dev-mydockerrepo/python:3.6-strech": image pull failed: Back-off pulling image "aie-docker-dev-mydockerrepo/python:3.6-strech". Check https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading for more information
```

I am trying to run job using gitlab runner. What could be the possible reason for failure ? I figured out ImagePullSecret could be set but I am not sure where to use that ? Anyone having idea ?

Answer (score 1):

According to:
https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/kubernetes.html#using-an-image-from-a-private-registry

If your Docker image is in a private repository, you need to create an image pull secret in the Kubernetes namespace where your job is running.

You can create an image pull secret using the following command

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry <SECRET_NAME> \
  --namespace <NAMESPACE> \
  --docker-server="https://<REGISTRY_SERVER>" \
  --docker-username="<REGISTRY_USERNAME>" \
  --docker-password="<REGISTRY_PASSWORD>"
```

Then configure the `image_pull_secrets` parameter in the Kubernetes executor config.toml settings.

```
[[runners]]
  [runners.kubernetes]
    image_pull_secrets = ["<SECRET_NAME>"]
```

Or if you use helm, `imagePullSecrets`

```
runners:
  imagePullSecrets: [your-image-pull-secret]
```

Keep in mind that in both cases you need to pass an array of secrets, even if you have only one.